# Why is it the data not updating immediately when I navigate to a different flutter page, but updates on refresh?

Tags: flutter, dart

Constant.dart

```
List<String> a= [];
List<String> b= [];
List<String> c= [];

List check = [a, b, c];
List<String> names= ["x", "y", "z"];

getFirebaseData(String date){
  _firestore.collection('something').doc('anything').get().then((value) => {
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
      check[i].clear(),
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (int j=0; j < 3; j++)
        {check[i].add(value.data()['${names[i]}'][date]['$j'])},
  });
}
```

Page 1

```
  void _onSelectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) async{
    final splitted = args.value.toString().split(' ');
    String date = splitted[0].toString();
    await getFirebaseData(date);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/page2');
  }
```

Page 2

```
    print("a" +a.toString());
    print("b" +b.toString());
    print("c" +c.toString());
```

Here, I am expecting the print blocks to be the values x, y and z. However I am not getting that when I am navigated to that page (Page 2). I am only getting data when I refresh the page (Page 2).

Why is this so? What must be done?

Comment: Can you include where the print statements are added in page 2?

Comment: It is included inside the build of a Stateful widget

Comment: I mean can you post it here